# GPS logging on the intel edison breakout board

Tags: c, gps

I'm working on my project car, and I have decided I would like to have a GPS and log some sensors too. I'm just at a bottle neck here, the sensors I have brought pull about 7v each where I can't pull that much from the breakout board that I have, and I can't seam to get the GPS to work.

I've tried using ths code but software serial isn't supported on the edison:

```
// GPS Setup
#define rxGPS 0
#define txGPS 1
SoftwareSerial serialGPS = SoftwareSerial(rxGPS, txGPS);
String stringGPS = "";

void setup() {
  pinMode(rxGPS, INPUT);
  pinMode(txGPS, OUTPUT);


  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Started");

  // GPS Setup
  serialGPS.begin(4800);
  digitalWrite(txGPS,HIGH);

  // Cut first gibberish
  while(serialGPS.available())
    if (serialGPS.read() == '\r')
      break;
}

void loop()
{
  String s = checkGPS();
  if(s && s.substring(0, 6) == "$GPGGA")
  {
    Serial.println(s);
  }
}

// Check GPS and returns string if full line recorded, else false
String checkGPS()
{
  if (serialGPS.available())
  {
    char c = serialGPS.read();
    if (c != '\n' && c != '\r')
    {
      stringGPS  = c;
    }
    else
    {
      if (stringGPS != "")
      {
        String tmp = stringGPS;
        stringGPS = "";
        return tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated

Comment: "Sensors pull 7V"? Hmm? Do they pull 7A? Or they need to be powered from 7V?

Comment: 1. stringGPS += c;

Comment: 2. checkGPS() returns String and you have "return false" at the end

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String GPSLine;

bool checkGPS()
{
  while(serialGPS.available())
  {
    char c = serialGPS.read();
    if(c == '\n') return true;
    if(c == '\r') continue;

    GPSLine += c;
  }
  return false;
}

void loop()
{
  if(checkGPS())
  {
    Serial.println(GPSLine);
    GPSLine = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: requiring any libraries?

Comment: Okay well to break up what I'm doing

Comment: 1 I have the Intel Edison one breakout board  it has a micro SD card slot and I want to take the gps and log everything that it sends to a SD card  and the second part is to read and display sensors onto a screen. But for now I just want to get the gps working

Answer (score 0):

You might try my [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) library.  It has a diagostic program and some good information in the [Troubleshooting section](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/doc/Troubleshooting.md).  And NeoGPS doesn't use the `String` class, although you can safely waste lots of RAM on the Edison.  :P

For an Edison build, you may have to change the PACKED_DATA configuration item, described [here](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/doc/Configurations.md#platforms).

(This is an Arduino product, right?)